# From where should Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll be loaded?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis

I need to use an SQL Server lib such as Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll. What is the best practice for identifying the correct .dll to load? Is there and environment variable or PowerShell variable that should be used?

There are -many- versions of this file on my system. How is a girl to choose?

```
PS C:\> dir -Recurse -Filter 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select CreationTime,Length,FullName

CreationTime        Length FullName
------------        ------ --------
2020-07-07 15:40:44 254736 C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18226\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management
2020-03-18 01:31:22 250976 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\
2020-04-16 16:39:24 254024 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\
2019-12-26 11:17:24 245856 C:\src\dbatools\bin\smo\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll
2020-06-24 09:04:24 250984 C:\Users\lit\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools\1.0.113\bin\smo\Microsoft.SqlSe
2020-02-11 12:40:24 254736 C:\Users\lit\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18218\Microsoft.SqlServer
2019-12-23 11:31:14 184000 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices\11.0.0.0__8984
2019-12-23 11:32:04 174784 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices\12.0.0.0__8984
2019-12-23 11:32:57 210624 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices\13.0.0.0__8984
2019-12-31 09:48:15 252584 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices\14.0.0.0__8984
```

Additional information:

The goal is to read some SSIS packages, apply logging settings, and save them back to disk. My research lead me to use SQL Server libraries. But, it is not clear how to select the correct library to load.

There are ten (10) "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll" files on my system. Does every tool and application feel that it should copy this into their own directory?

Would looking into the .dtsx file specify which SQL Server library version should be used. The packages are currently running on SQL Server 2016. Are these indicators?

```
DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="14.0.3002.113"
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=13.0.0.0, Cult...
```

Comment: Select the appropriate version from the GAC, i.e. 14.0.0.0...

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz, thanks. Given that there are four (4) GAC_MISL directories on my system (11, 12, 13, and 14), how would I reliably go about selecting the correct one? It cannot be the most recent CreationTime or LastWriteTime. Is the highest number (14) is always right?

Comment: What task you load DLL for? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This would depend on which version of SSIS you want to use.  14 is SQL 2017, 13 is SQL 2016, 12 is SQL 2014.  I would guess you'd want the latest..  You'd also want this to be consistent with wherever your code is getting deployed to.

Answer (score 2):

Mark & Ferdipux have it right - you likely want what is in the GAC.

SSIS assemblies are version specific

- 15 := SQL Server 2019
- 14 := SQL Server 2017
- 13 := SQL Server 2016
- 12 := SQL Server 2014
- 11 := SQL Server 2012
- 10.5 := SQL Server 2008R2
- 10 := SQL Server 2008
- 9 := SQL Server 2005

You will need to align your application assemblies with the version of SQL Server you will be deploying your application to.

As you've identified you are going to be creating SSIS packages targeting SQL Server 2016, then you'll want the the assembly `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices\13.0.0.0__8984`

Comment: This is helpful information, but I still need to know which version should be used. I have added information to the question about the desired goal. I thought my research brought me to a succinct question, but apparently not. Sorry.

Comment: You'll want assemblies associated with 13 aka sql server 2016

Comment: Yes, that is clear from the table you gave. How will the code select the correct library. Does that need to be a parameter or configuration requirement? Are the .ddl file guaranteed to be on C:? I would rather not hardcode a path to the .ddl files. How will this work on Linux?

Comment: @lit, I usually end up having a general project in VS with all logic, and sided projects with  project custom property like `SQL2016`. The general project refers all top DLLs, and sided project refers DLLs for corresponding SSIS version. Then you compile and run appropriate project. SSIS does not work on Linux so you may not worry on this.

Comment: @Ferdipux, does this mean that the `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Micr...` path is hardcoded based on the custom property? Can it ever be installed such that the GAC_MSIL directory is on a different volume: `D:` or `F:`?